# Google OAuth2.0 React (@react-oauth/google) not working in AWS EC2

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, https, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

Previously, I used the "@react-oauth/google" package to authenticate users on my website. During development, my React app was running on "localhost:3000," and the Spring Boot backend was on "localhost:8080." I had configured the allowed origin and redirect URL to "http://localhost:3000," and everything worked perfectly. The user response was obtained in the frontend and then sent to the backend, where it was stored in the database.

Recently, I deployed my website to an EC2 instance. However, I encountered an issue with authentication because requests were now originating from EC2's public URL instead of "localhost:3000." This public URL was not included in the allowed list, causing authentication to fail.

Moreover, my website currently operates on HTTP, not HTTPS. Google's authentication system doesn't permit the use of HTTP addresses for domains in the allowed list or the redirect URL list. As a result, my HTTP domain is neither allowed nor included in the redirect URL list.

To address this issue, I am considering setting up a load balancer that uses HTTPS and forwards traffic to my frontend using HTTP. My question is whether adding the load balancer's URL to my Google app's allowed list would solve the problem and allow successful authentication.

I am not very well versed with the workings of these protocols so correct me if I am wrong anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You're right. You need to put your EC2 instance behind a load balancer/gateway. You need two things here:

1. As you noticed, the redirect URI must be an HTTPS URL, so you need to put your EC2 behind SSL.
2. You need a static URL, one that won't change every time your EC2 instance changes (e.g., because you redeploy your application, scale to more instances, etc.)

Normally you would have a domain and use that domain in your redirect URI.